# How to find CSS deceleration for :hover state using Chrome's inspector

Tags: html, css, border, prettyphoto

I am creating the following gallery:

[gallery](http://gregorydanelian.comule.com/ken/)

I believe that there prettyPhoto.css is applying a border-color on hover but I can't seem to locate it using the Dom Inspector.

Can anyone help me locate the css to edit the border color on hover?

Comment: That's a better idea to share some code, instead of linking images, as there is chance, the image's link get broken after a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using Chrome's inspector( `(Ctrl+Shift+I)` while in a **Google Chrome** browser windows), you may click on `Toggle Element State`, while you have pointed the correct DOM element:

[image]

and, there you may find checkboxes, to activate the :

- Hover
- Active
- Focus
- Visited

states for the element.

Answer (score 1):

That would be at line 9 of the bootstrap.min.css :

```
a.thumbnail:hover, a.thumbnail:focus{
border-color: #08c;
}
```